# Appengine application not working when deployed - TemplateNotFound. It works on localhost

Tags: google-app-engine

I am facing same issue with google app engine application. It works on SDK (localhost), not working when uploaded to appengine. Deployment was successful. I am stuck on this!!! Any help appreciated.

Traceback logs below:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cloud-chess/1.368562751153844474/chessboard.py", line 29, in get
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('files/html/chess.html')
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py", line 719, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py", line 693, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/loaders.py", line 115, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/loaders.py", line 180, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
TemplateNotFound: files/html/chess.html
```

Deployment Logs:

```
01:56 PM Host: appengine.google.com
01:56 PM Application: cloud-chess; version: 2
01:56 PM 
Starting update of app: cloud-chess, version: 2
01:56 PM Getting current resource limits.
Password for xxxx.pk@gmail.com: 01:56 PM Scanning files on local disk.
01:56 PM Cloning 17 static files.
01:56 PM Cloning 3 application files.
01:56 PM Uploading 1 files and blobs.
01:56 PM Uploaded 1 files and blobs
01:56 PM Compilation starting.
01:57 PM Compilation completed.
01:57 PM Starting deployment.
01:57 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
01:57 PM Deployment successful.
01:57 PM Checking if updated app version is serving.
01:57 PM Completed update of app: cloud-chess, version: 2
01:57 PM Uploading index definitions.
2013-07-07 13:57:18 (Process exited with code 0)
```

chessboard.py

```
import os

import webapp2
import jinja2


JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'])

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('files/html/chess.html')
        self.response.write(template.render())

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

app.yaml

```
application: cloud-chess
version: 2
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /html
  static_dir: files/html/

- url: /images
  static_dir: files/images/

- url: /scripts
  static_dir: files/scripts/

- url: .*
  script: chessboard.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Comment: Define what you mean by not working.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the templates your are trying to load are residing in your static directive `html` .

There is no need to deploy templates as static resources - in fact you probably shouldn't.

When you deploy static resources they are not normally readable by your application.
Recently an `app.yaml` directive was added to allow you to read these resources.

Unless there is html files you wish to statically serve, just drop the `/html` static directive, or move your templates somewhere else.

or add the directive.   `application_readable` to the `/html` static handler

see the docs for static handlers https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_Directory_Handlers

Personally I would recommend against being able to statically serve jinja templates as well use them for rendering.

Why does this work in the dev environment - the dev environment doesn't use different storage mechanisms for serving static and application readable resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store your templates in a static directory.

Simply remove the `/html` handler from app.yaml like so:

```
application: cloud-chess
version: 2
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /images
  static_dir: files/images/

- url: /scripts
  static_dir: files/scripts/

- url: .*
  script: chessboard.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```